# How to generate random positive floating point numbers with normal distribution from 0 up to a given ceiling?

Tags: c#, random, .net-core, floating-point, intervals

I need to generate a number of `float` numbers with approximately normal distribution over a range from 0 to a specific ceiling.

I've searched on stack overflow and found similar questions for other languages, but none for .net core.

```
internal List<float> function(int ceiling, int repetitions)
{
    List<float> list = new List<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i<= repetitions;i++)
    {
         list.Add(Random.nextFloat() * ceiling);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I expect the function to return a `list` of random  positive `float`numbers, in range from 0 to a given ceiling with at least approximately normal distribution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.8 Instantiate your `Random` before the `for` - call this method inside the `for`.

Comment: Please add example results as well as desired results.

Comment: A *normal distribution* doesn't have a ceiling, nor does it start from 0. Are you by chance talking about a *uniform distribution*? That would match the code you posted.

Comment: Normal distribution can start from 0, and you could form a normal distribution of data where the highest value is considered the ceiling.

Comment: I assume if the maximum is intended to be X, the mean will be X/2. What do you want for the standard deviation? Will it be small enough to make values outside [0,X] very low probability?

Comment: The quoted code samples a uniform distribution, not a normal distribution.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu No, you couldn't. The normal distribution has infinite support.

Comment: @Dirk, I forgot to add **approximately** to the question, edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeking something "at least approximately normal" with bounds at 0 and `ceiling`, summing three uniforms will yield a result which is symmetric, bell-shaped, and bounded, and can subsequently be rescaled to any range you wish.  I'm not a C# programmer, but if you have a PRNG named `prng`:

```
(prng.NextDouble() + prng.NextDouble() + prng.NextDouble()) * ceiling / 3.0
```

will yield a result in the range `[0, ceiling]`.  Here's what 100,000 observations look like with `ceiling` set to 3:

[image: Sum of 3 uniforms histogram is symmetric, bell-shaped, and bounded]

You can generalize this to sum `k` uniforms and replace the 3 by `k` in the divisor for the rescaling.  The larger `k` is, the closer this will get to normality by the central limit theorem, but since you don't seem to be asking for actual normals (which don't have a bounded range anyway) that quickly gets into diminishing returns.

Note that while this approach uses multiple uniforms, it is computationally relatively efficient because it avoids transcendental functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use truncated normal together with taking absolute values to make result positive.

Along the lines

```
double R = 10.0; // upper value of the truncated normal

var seed = 31234567;
Random rng = new Random( seed );

double u1 = rng.NextDouble();
double u2 = rng.NextDouble();

double phi = 2.0*Math.PI*u2;
double r   = Math.Sqrt(-2.0*Math.Log(1.0 - u1*(1.0 - Math.Exp(-R*R/2.0))));

return new Tuple<double,double>(Math.Abs(r*Math.Cos(phi)), Math.Abs(r*Math.Sin(phi)));
```

Code above shall return couple of sampled values in the interval from 0 to R which looks like truncated gaussian. You could compare with [Box-Muller](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html) for standard gaussain sampling